# EF Automatic Migration not working with virtual property

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, database-migration, entity-framework-4.3

I am trying to use automatic migration with entity framework and code first. I added new property to my class (Team is also custom class):

```
public virtual Team SecondTeam { get; set; }
```

and I have problem with updating database. After I write command I get this in my console:

> Direct column renaming is not supported by SQL Server Compact. To
>   rename a column in SQL Server Compact, you will need to recreate it.

Normally is updating working (I tried to add simple int prop and it just updates) but I have problem if that is virtual. Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you

Edit: All lines after `Update-Database -Verbose`

```
Using NuGet project 'Project'.  
Using StartUp project 'Project'.  
Target database is: '|DataDirectory|database.sdf' (DataSource: |DataDirectory|database.sdf, Provider: System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0, Origin: Configuration). 
No pending explicit migrations. 
Applying automatic migration: 201206130828142_AutomaticMigration. 
Direct column renaming is not supported by SQL Server Compact. To rename a column in SQL Server Compact, you will need to recreate it.
```

Edit2:
Player class where I want to change database:

```
public class Player
    {
        [Key]
        public int PlayerID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Nickname { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birth { get; set; }

        public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
        public string Post { get; set; }

        public int TeamID { get; set; }
        public virtual Team Team { get; set; }

        public int SecondTeamID { get; set; }
        public virtual Team SecondTeam { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

Team class:

```
public class Team
    {
        [Key]
        public int TeamID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string League { get; set; }
        public string Trainings { get; set; }

        public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }

        public int CoachID { get; set; }
        public int AassistantID { get; set; }
        public int ManagerID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }

        public bool showPosts { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is SQL generated by EF:

```
CREATE TABLE "Players" (
    "PlayerID" int not null identity,
    "Name" nvarchar(4000) not null,
    "Surname" nvarchar(4000) not null,
    "Nickname" nvarchar(4000) null,
    "Birth" datetime not null,
    "PhotoUrl" nvarchar(4000) null,
    "Post" nvarchar(4000) null,
    "TeamID" int not null,
    "SecondTeamID" int not null,
    "UserId" int not null,
    "Team_TeamID" int null,
    "Team_TeamID1" int null,
    "SecondTeam_TeamID" int null,
    PRIMARY KEY ("PlayerID")
);

ALTER TABLE "Players" ADD CONSTRAINT "Team_Players" FOREIGN KEY ("Team_TeamID") REFERENCES "Teams"("TeamID");
ALTER TABLE "Players" ADD CONSTRAINT "Player_Team" FOREIGN KEY ("Team_TeamID1") REFERENCES "Teams"("TeamID");
ALTER TABLE "Players" ADD CONSTRAINT "Player_SecondTeam" FOREIGN KEY ("SecondTeam_TeamID") REFERENCES "Teams"("TeamID");
ALTER TABLE "Players" ADD CONSTRAINT "Player_User" FOREIGN KEY ("UserId") REFERENCES "Users"("UserID") ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Run `Update-Database -Script` to see what it's trying to rename, or use the `-Verbose` option to find out more.

Comment: I tried it but It didn´t help me much.

Comment: Post the generated SQL and whole code of your entity into your question. It looks like EF thinks that you renamed property instead of adding new property.

Comment: Any specific reason why you have fields like `int SecondTeamID` in addition to the `virtual Team SecondTeam`? That column is redundant, and I have a hunch that it could be confusing the change detection logic.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but I think the solution can be useful later.

Do not use, unless you are sure the code is restricted to a debugging environment, the `RecreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` feature. If it slips in production code (and you're probably not always looking at the DAL before a release) unexpected data loss can easily become an issue.

If you're correctly using Migrations, you'll see that EF generates code like this for you:

```
namespace Migrations_CE
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class TargetInventoryChange : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            RenameColumn(table: "dbo.TargetInventoryItems", name: "MatchedPrinter_ID", newName: "MatchedPrinterID");
            AddColumn("dbo.TargetInventoryItems", "CustomerID", c => c.String(maxLength: 40));
            AlterColumn("dbo.TargetInventoryItems", "Name", c => c.String(maxLength: 100));
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            AlterColumn("dbo.TargetInventoryItems", "Name", c => c.String(maxLength: 4000));
            DropColumn("dbo.TargetInventoryItems", "CustomerID");
            RenameColumn(table: "dbo.TargetInventoryItems", name: "MatchedPrinterID", newName: "MatchedPrinter_ID");
        }
    }
}
```

In this particular project I keep TWO sets of migrations, one for SQL CE databases, and one for SQL Server. While producing migrations for the Compact edition I stumbled upon your problem.

I solved it just doing what the error message said. **Note that it will lead to data loss on the columns you are renaming.** Be careful.

This example solves the foreign key case, which is (I believe) one of the worst, since EF generates the column, the FK constraint and an automatic index - on its own.

```
public override void Up()
{
    //RenameColumn(table: "dbo.TargetInventoryItems", name: "MatchedPrinter_ID", newName: "MatchedPrinterID");
    DropIndex("dbo.TargetInventoryItems", "IX_MatchedPrinter_ID");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.TargetInventoryItems", "FK_dbo.TargetInventoryItems_dbo.CustPrinters_MatchedPrinter_ID");
    DropColumn("dbo.TargetInventoryItems", "MatchedPrinter_ID");
    AddColumn("dbo.TargetInventoryItems", "MatchedPrinterID", c => c.Int());
    AddForeignKey("dbo.TargetInventoryItems", "MatchedPrinterID", "dbo.CustPrinters", "ID");
    CreateIndex("dbo.TargetInventoryItems", "MatchedPrinterID", unique: false);
}
```

If you don't know the name of the Index, you can look at the particular table with SQL CE Toolbox (http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/). You will see a list of indices, where you'll find the name to delete.

For the FK constraint you have to query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, e.g. using again SQL CE Toolbox, with a query like

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
```

Put some `WHERE` conditions as needed. I hope this will be fixed on the appropriate SQL generator, but in the meanwhile this actually solves the problem - for small changes.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but how do you maintain a 2nd set of migrations?

Comment: I've since moved on from that project, but I remember having something like a custom class set as DbConfiguration for the context. In that class, depending on some configuration value (in my app's XML config file), I did instantiate the SQL CE or the SQLSrv drivers and connection strings. I simply ran the powershell EF tools for managing migrations after having the configuration updated, and specifying the correct "Migrations" directory (/namespace). Same for migrator: choose the correct Configuration class from the right namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you follow this sample [Steven Sanderson - MvcScaffolding: One-to-Many Relationships](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/28/mvcscaffolding-one-to-many-relationships/) and during development time use the feature to recreate the database at startup as per [Scott Guthrie - Code-First Development with Entity Framework 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) blog. (Search for the paragraph `Taking advantage of SQL CE 4` and `The RecreateDatabaseIfModelChanges Feature`)